# when I set desktop icons hidden I can not change wallpaper

Tags: desktop-background, .desktop

I have Ubuntu 13.10 32 bit. When I set desktop icons false, I can not change wallpaper.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
```

When It boots up I meet a black desktop. I used to apply the same setting in Ubuntu 13.04 without any problem.

Which settings do I miss to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in terminal:

gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true

A site: 
http://lifehacker.com/5581364/reset-gnome-when-things-go-wrong-on-your-linux-desktop

Or reset your gnome desktop.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I forgot that I played with that setting when I got invisible mouse.